# gem install rails fails with "typeerror no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the rails gem by executing `gem install rails` and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Installed ruby versions using rbenv:

```
$ rbenv versions
system
* 2.3.1 (set by /Users/Michael/.rbenv/version)
```

I'm on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: Is it just rails or all gems?

Comment: I tried gem install bundler and it worked.